# Did Perry's Black Ships attack Edo harbour during his expedition to Japan?

Tags: 19th-century, japan, naval, diplomacy, meiji-restoration

Matthew C. Perry commanded the U.S. Navy expedition that forced Japan to abandon its [policy of isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakoku), triggering the eventual overthrow of the [Shogunate's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokugawa_shogunate) and the [Meiji Restoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiji_Restoration). Perry arrived in [Edo Bay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Bay) in 1853 to deliver a letter from [President Fillmore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millard_Fillmore), and returned the next year to receive Japan's answer. By demonstrating the overwhelming superiority of Western technology, he forced the Japanese delegates to agree to his demands.

In the [English Wikipedia article for Commodore Perry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_C._Perry), it is mentioned that, when the Japanese tried to turn him away during the first visit, Perry ordered his ships to attack the habour with highly destructive guns. That article cites as a source Arthur Walworth's book, the [*Black Ships Off Japan: The Story of Commodore Perry's Expedition*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/140675529X).

> Perry ordered some buildings in the harbor shelled. (Walworth,Arthur; Black Ships Off Japan p. 21) Perry's ships were equipped with new Paixhans shell guns, cannons capable of wreaking great explosive destruction with every shell.
>
> <sub>[**- Matthew_C._Perry - Threat of force and negotiation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_C._Perry#Threat_of_force_and_negotiation)</sub>

In contrast, the Japanese article says the cannons fired blanks and did not result in any deaths. This seems to match what the [Naval History and Heritage Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_History_%26_Heritage_Command) says, hich seems to suggest (based on the wording of "implied") that the guns weren't actually used on the Japanese.

> During this period, the Commodore remained out of sight in his cabin, stating that he would consult personally only with direct representatives of the Emperor. The Japanese procrastinated and equivocated. The Commodore stood firm, **supported by the *implied* threat of the squadron's guns**. He refused to move his ships to Nagasaki. He rejected gifts and compromises. He forbade indiscriminate visiting by natives. He herded their guard boats away from the anchorage. Always alert to the possibility of treachery, he exercised his crew at battle stations daily.
>
> <sub>[**- A brief Summary of the Perry Expedition to Japan, 1853**](http://www.history.navy.mil/library/online/perry_exp.htm)</sub>

The two versions seem to be contradictory. Moreover, although the English wiki mentioned no deaths, it followed the sentence by saying Perry's ships were equipped with devastating gun, which seems like they would have easily killed people had they fired.

So my question is, **is it definitively known whether Perry attacked the harbour to forcibly open Japan?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the contemporary accounts I have read, such as that of Francis L. Hawks (1861), which is more or less the official account of the missions, make any mention of an attack of any kind. In the Hawks narrative the embassy is presented as entirely peaceful.

Also, the text of the letter which Millard Fillmore gave to Perry for delivery to the Emperor specifically says that he had ordered Perry not to do anything "which would disturb the peace of Japan".

There is a book written by an eye witness, John Smith Sewall. "The Logbook of the Captain's Clerk" published in 1905. Sewall was the clerk to the Captain of one of the escorts of the expedition. Nowhere in this book does he mention any shots or "blanks" fired and he represents the embassy as peaceful except for three shells fired by the Japanese which exploded harmlessly behind them when they first arrived. These shots by the Japanese are also mentioned in the Hawks narrative.

Comment: Does what you read corroborate what the Japanese Wiki says about firing blank shells, or do they present a different account? Also, in the Japanese perspective at least Perry's ships committed an act of war by sailing into Edo Harbour - do you have a source that Fillmore quote? Google turns up this very page.

Comment: I don't know what the Japanese "wiki" says. What I do know is that the official book written about the embassy never mentions any hostilities. In fact, the trip involved many highly elaborate greetings and ceremonies, which probably would not have happened if shots had been fired. Also, in the part of the narrative where they pass the coastal fortifications of Edo, they describe them as "under construction", in other words, not in an operable state to be exchanging gunfire.

Comment: As far as the contents of Fillmore's letter to the emperor you can find that in "Messages and Correspondence of the Presidents" by Richardson which you can find in any large library or in Google Books.

Comment: The Japanese wiki's version of events is stated in the question *as well as the comment* you are supposedly replying to - namely, that Perry fired blanks. Also, no one else said anything about "exchanging gunfire" - the question is whether Perry fired blanks or actually attacked. Or, as you seem to be saying, he didn't fire at all; which is a valid answer, but not very well substantiated right now.

Comment: Also, it is quite misleading to put your own paraphrasing of some source text in between quotation marks as though it's an actual quote. I don't think it is productive to pursue this angle however since whatever Fillmore's diplomatic letter says doesn't really determine what Perry actually did later.

Comment: @Semaphore The most official account of the trip does not say anywhere that cannons or sidearms were ever fired at the Japanese. The wiki article on Perry is misquoting Walworth's book. There is a private, unpublished diary by an officer on the flagship of the mission at the Massachusetts Historical Society. If it will satisfy you I will go and read this diary, because if guns had every been fired it would be a certainty that the officer would have noted it in his diary as an important event. If all you want to do is make up a war which never existed I won't waste my time.

Comment: **No one except you** said anything about "a war". If all you want to do is twist this question into something it isn't, then kindly stop wasting my time. Many books speak of Perry firing his guns to apply pressure. You're free to call them all wrong by strawmaning that into "a war which never existed" but don't expect me to take your word for it.

Comment: @Semaphore I have discovered that there is another book by an eye witness, which I have cited in my answer.

Comment: @Semaphore What do you mean "many books" say this? What books? The only citation you give is a wiki page. What books have you ACTUALLY READ that say the black ships fired their guns? I have now cited two books, one compiled from the journals of Perry himself, the other by an eye-witness to the journey, neither of which mention any guns being fired.

Comment: @Semaphore As for "war" language, your question reads "is it definitively known whether Perry attacked the harbour". I think attacking a harbor might be construed as an act of war.

Comment: Then the act of war of invading Japanese territorial waters meant your "war which never existed" was in fact a very existent war. Since your responses are really just argumentative and increasingly offtopic I'm just going to ignore this now. But what you've really done is cite primary sources and demand they be accepted uncritically as the *whole* truth - even though one *has clear reason for bias* and the other speaks of *teaching "haughty" Japan how to behave*. This answer would be much better had it included writings from someone critical of Perry such as interpreter Williams' diary.

Comment: Respectfully, I'm not surprised that official accounts of the US don't mention hostility. People usually don't voluntarily make themselves look like the meanie.

Comment: Nevertheless I will upvote this answer for presenting an alternate view of Perry's mission being "entirely peaceful", even though I do not find it sufficiently persuasive as it stands to mark it accepted. And yup, exactly what @Juicy said.

Comment: @Juicy I am very suspicious and critical of official coverups, but in this case I don't see any evidence of it. If you read the Hawks narrative, which is gigantic by the way (3 volumes), it goes on and on and on about one tedious tea ceremony after another. All through the narrative are described all sorts of elaborate precautions they are taking to prevent a sailor so much as firing a pistol. Every visit ashore is this huge deal, with exchange of letters and flags and so on. The idea of a cannon being fired just does not jive with anything in the book, nor with later accounts, like Sewalls.

Comment: True, I must say I simply don't know much about this so I'm not going to refute your arguments. From my lecture though I remember that they were *threatened*. One could argue that an entirely peaceful mission could be done with something else than a military vessel. But like I said, I don't have any sources to back either way.

Comment: @Juicy From the narrative there were never any threats spoken or written. The "threat" was just showing up fully armed, an implied threat. According to the official narrative the high point of tension occurred at the beginning when the Japanese refused to meet Perry in state and he wrote to them that he would be "insulted" if he was not met in state. In Japan, saying that might be insulted by something is fairly strong language.

Comment: Miyamato Musashi, dusty from a long morning's walk, is said to have been enjoying lunchtime soup in a roadside inn when two ronin eyed his katana and made movements suggesting a robbery. Determined to both enjoy his soup undisturbed, and to preserve the peace and harmony of the inn, Musashi calmly dispossessed two nearby flies of their wings with his wakazashi. Being observant, the two ronin quietly continued by Musashi's table out of the inn and don the road.  ...

Comment: The Japanese would most certainly have completely understood the meaning of a warship sailing quietly into Edo harbour. Just as definitively, an unescorted merchant ship doing the same would never have been heard from again, *lost at sea* in some unknown typhoon, if it ever managed to enter the harbour. The flies were dispossess of wings in mid-iar, left to roam Musashis' table wingless but otherwise unharmed.

Answer (score 5):

Not being a native speaker of English, my interpretation might not be correct, but this is a quote from "Narrative of the expedition of an American Squadron to the China Seas and Japan";

---

"The Japanese officials took especial interest, on the occasion of their frequent visits to the ships in the inspection of the armament, and were often **gratified with the exercise of the guns**, the filling of the shells, and other matters of military discipline and practice. Though, in their later history a pacific people, the Japanese, as we have already said, are fond of military display, and seemed particularly desirous of scrutinizing all the warlike appointments which made their visitors so formidable; as if they felt the necessity, in the new relations which were opening with foreigners, of studying and adopting the best means of attack and defence, should either ever become necessary by any future collision with the great powers of the west. With proper training, no people would make better soldiers. Every opportunity was afforded them, without restriction, of satisfying their curiosity, which was naturally directed towards those points in which they were conscious of their greatest weakness; and this liberality of the Americans, in the free exposition of their power, deeply impressed the Japanese with a conviction of the pacific intentions of their visitors, who desired to show that they looked to a friendly intercourse, and not to a violent invasion, for those mutual benefits which were to accrue from more intimate relations between the United States and Japan."

---

The bold is mine. Could this not be interpreted, by Japanese speakers, as the guns being fired for demonstration? This from their visit in Hakodate, similar demonstrations most likely occurred in Edo bay, but I don't have the time or resources to llok for that right now. The above quote is from page 470 and forward in volume one.